# Control page at the first file

Tags: android, android-activity

I want to create app which have a tip page =show how to use this app and at tip page have 2 button (skip and continue)if user press skip button it view go to main page and if press continue button it will show another tip

and at the main page user can set the value "show tip box at the first time" if user don't want to show tip box user can check this and next time user use this app it will show main page as the first page

so I have to create control page to check the value show tip box at the first time in database before show tip page or main page and the problem is I don't want to show control page

How to resolve this problem

What should I do with my Manifest

Answer (score 0):

U can use shared preference for this..

```
    static SharedPreferences notify_Settings;
    public static SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "Desired Name";
    notify_Settings=getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = notify_Settings.edit();

   if (settings.getBoolean("firsttime", false) == false ){ 
      editor.putBoolean("firsttime",true;
      editor.commit();
      //Some code here
      startActivity(new Intent(Page 1.this, Page 2.class)); 
   }else{
      //Some code here
        startActivity(new Intent(Page 1.this, Page 3.class)); 
   }
```

First time it will return false since there will be no value (i.e) false  in the shared preference so if (condition) gets true and do your procees and Redirect the page to the Page 2.class

If you run the application again this condition will become false since the value in shared preference will be "true" now so this way you can control your page Redirections..

Comment: Also take a look at this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html